# what is the difference between hadoop -appendToFile versus hadoop -put when used for updating stream data into hdfs continously

Tags: file, hadoop, append, hdfs

As per hadoop source code following descriptions are pulled out from the classes -

**appendToFile**

```
"Appends the contents of all the given local files to the
given dst file. The dst file will be created if it does not exist."
```

**put**

```
    "Copy files from the local file system into fs. Copying fails if the file already exists, unless the -f flag is given.
Flags:
-p : Preserves access and modification times, ownership and the mode.
-f : Overwrites the destination if it already exists.
-l : Allow DataNode to lazily persist the file to disk. Forces
replication factor of 1. This flag will result in reduced
durability. Use with care.
-d : Skip creation of temporary file(<dst>._COPYING_)."
```

I am trying to update a file into hdfs regularly as it is being updated dynamically from a streaming source in my local File System.

Which one should I use out of appendToFile and put, and Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendToFile` modifies the existing file in HDFS, so only the new data needs to be streamed/written to the filesystem.

`put` rewrites the entire file, so the entire new version of the file needs to be streamed/written to the filesystem.

You should favor `appendToFile` if you are just appending to the file (i.e. adding logs to the end of a file). This function will be faster if that's your use case. If the file is changing more than just simple appends to the end, you should use `put` (slower but you won't lose data or corrupt your file).